# mysql query adding columns from different table with left join for null values

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, inner-join

I have a query that has two sum with different columns from different tables. I am able to get the total of the two SUM queries but i have a problem regarding displaying all the data with null values from my tbl_overtime_paid. Also i want to add a condition from my query to add only those who have tbl_salary_daily.status = 0 and tbl_overtime_paid.status = 0.

My table structure is something like this:
[image]

I want an output like these:

```
firstname   middlename  lastname    name_ext    sum_amount_paid sum_salary  sum_total
Invader     Jesus       Jesus       Jr.         0               358.75      358.75
Jane        Jesus       Jesus       Jr.         0               380.62      380.62
John        Jesus       Jesus       Jr.         0               350         350
Liza        Jesus       Jesus       Jr.         0               385         385
Rey         Jesus       Jesus       Jr.         98.44           801.35      899.79
```

Here is a sql fiddle  for the structure : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9615b5/1/0

Comment: A fiddle is good but--Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initializations) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debuging fundamental.) Also: Why rows are missing from a left join & why multiple aggregations are wrong are faqs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your query. move your `AND tbl_overtime_paid.status = 0` to `left join`.
adding this in `where` clause will filter everything based on this criteria

```
SELECT DISTINCT tbl_user.firstname,
  tbl_user.middlename,
  tbl_user.lastname,
  tbl_user.name_ext,
  sum(coalesce(tbl_overtime_paid.amount_paid,0)),
  sum(coalesce(t1.salary,0)),
  sum(coalesce(t1.salary,0)+coalesce(tbl_overtime_paid.amount_paid,0))
FROM tbl_user
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT sum(salary) as salary, employee_id from tbl_salary_daily
     WHERE `status` = 0 
     group by employee_id) as t1 on tbl_user.employee_id = t1.employee_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_overtime_paid ON tbl_overtime_paid.employee_id = t1.employee_id AND tbl_overtime_paid.`status` = 0
GROUP BY tbl_user.firstname,
  tbl_user.middlename,
  tbl_user.lastname,
  tbl_user.name_ext
```

Comment: @metal, its almost correct. pleas take a look in my tbl_overtime_paid. i have only two values, the one has status = 1, i want to exclude it from adding

Comment: yea.. i see my main problem? so can you suggest me how would i re-structure my table? in order to get what i want ?, or is it impossible to get what i want base on query ?